# Nodejs HTTPS in Windows server

Tags: node.js, ssl, iis, iis-10

As state in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61326944/iis-reverse-proxy-2-subdomain-to-2-node-js) in a project used IIS reverse-proxy where in the IIS had a certificated installed and used in two sites where each with a subdomain and with the reverse-proxy point internaly to a port for example localhost:8080 and the other to port localhost:8081.

[image]

where had Enabled SSL Offloading selected, it works well.

But have some doubts is there any probleam in question of security if the HTTPS request foward to HTTP but since its internaly seems to me it should be okay?

Second is for the scenario above wouldn't need in Nodejs project to change the

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
```

to

```
   const options = {
     key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
     cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
   };
   var server = https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
```

In this case would start to use the https module and this two files of the certificate key.pem and cert.pem would only need to have this two files or is it needed any more configuration

How would generate this two files from a cer file using the openssl lib or to generate the certificate file to install in IIS if the cer is a OV certificate?

So what would be the best approach install the certificate in iis and use reverse-proxy or in nodejs start using the https module and point to the certificate (key.pem and cert.pem).

-------------------------Edit----------------------------------------------------

[image]

Comment: was able to install the certificate in iis only needed to convert to another format

Comment: It seems that you are just using reverse proxy. So you don't have to select Enable SSL-offloading in IIS beause it is used for ARR load balance farm. Forward https to http should be secure becuase it only happened between your IIS server and client won't reach your backend server directly.  Now that IIS just works as a proxy. you don't have to specify certificate in nodejs side. You just have to enable https in your backend server binding. So that the connection between your IIS servers will be secured.

Comment: @JokiesDing thanks for the answer, so disabled the SSL-offloading but now receiving in request a 502 since in nodejs using the http so now need to update to https when https.createServer what do i pass in the options parameters? (since don't need to specify certificate)

Comment: Also in the bindings already had https, when refered to the certificated installed also meant it was configured in IIS in the bindings https using the certificate. So when called the url its already working as https but as you refered don't need the SSL-offloading that means in nodejs need to use the https model/package right?